# Average of previous and next value in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, dictionary

I want to write a function where I input a date and an integer in dictionary and it returns the sum of the integers in the form of keys of day on that date.

I also want if there is no certain day in the dictionary instead of returning 0 in the value; the value of the dictionary should return the average of the previous and next element.

There is the code that I have written:

```
import calendar
from datetime import datetime
def cal(D):
    add = dict(zip(calendar.day_abbr, [0] * 7))
    for date, value in D.items():
        add[datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%a")] += value

    kList = sorted(add.keys())
    for key,value in enumerate(kList):
        if(value == 0):
            value = (add[kList+1] + add[kList-1])/ 2

    return add

D = {'2020-01-01': 6, '2020-01-04': 12, '2020-01-05': 14, '2020-01-06': 2, '2020-01-07': 4}

print(cal(D))
```

O/P:

```
{'Mon': 2, 'Tue': 4, 'Wed': 6, 'Thu': 0, 'Fri': 0, 'Sat': 12, 'Sun': 14}
```

expected O/P:

```
{'Mon': 2, 'Tue': 4, 'Wed': 6, 'Thu': 8, 'Fri': 10, 'Sat': 12, 'Sun': 14}
```

Assuming every input has a Sunday and a Monday.

Comment: @horcrux thu and fri are not there in the input so it should return the average of previous and next element.

Comment: shouldn't 'Thu' equal to (6 + 12) / 2 = 9 ?

Comment: No, that's the problem the algorithm should be efficient,  Thu - 6+10/2 likewise Fri - 8+12/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula that you want is the following:

```
(prev * succ_distance + succ * prev_distance) / total_distance
```

Indeed, it is important how distant the two days are, therefore you can't just do the mean dividing by 2, but you have to use a **weighted average**.

This is the code:

```
import calendar
from datetime import datetime
def cal(D):
    add = dict(zip(calendar.day_abbr, [0] * 7))
    for date, value in D.items():
        add[datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%a")] += value

    kList = list(add.keys())
    
    def find_next(i, step) :
            next_val = 0
            distance = 0
            while next_val == 0 :
                distance+=1
                next_val = add[kList[i+distance*step]];
            return next_val, distance
    
    for i, day in enumerate(kList):
        if(add[day] == 0):
            prev, p_distance = find_next(i, -1)
            succ, s_distance = find_next(i, +1)
            total_distance = p_distance + s_distance
            add[day] = (prev * s_distance + succ * p_distance) // total_distance

    return add

D = {'2020-01-01': 6, '2020-01-04': 12, '2020-01-05': 14, '2020-01-06': 2, '2020-01-07': 4}

print(cal(D))
```

---

#### Possible optimization

Since your list is sorted, you can assume that the previous value is different from `0`. Therefore, you can do as follows:

```
import calendar
from datetime import datetime
def cal(D):
    add = dict(zip(calendar.day_abbr, [0] * 7))
    for date, value in D.items():
        add[datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%a")] += value

    kList = list(add.keys())
    
    for i, day in enumerate(kList):
        if(add[day] == 0):
            prev = add[kList[i-1]]
            succ = 0
            s_distance = 0
            while succ == 0 :
                s_distance += 1
                succ = add[kList[i + s_distance]];
            
            add[day] = (prev * s_distance + succ) // (s_distance +1)

    return add

D = {'2020-01-01': 6, '2020-01-04': 12, '2020-01-05': 14, '2020-01-06': 2, '2020-01-07': 4}

print(cal(D))
```